# Clicklifter showing up in ETag

Tags: etag, yslow

I just ran *YSlow* on my site and this shows up under ETag:

```
http://content.clicklifter.com/Learning/learn.js
```

I have no idea what it is or how to get rid of it and I can't find any info about this anywhere.

Can someone at least tell me how I can get rid of it if I do not see it in my view source but it shows up in *YSlow* under "configure entity tags"?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely this script is being brought in by another script or an ad on your site. If that's the case, you won't see it in view source, but tools like YSlow will reveal it.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I know this question is old but the same happened to me and it was because a JavaScript I downloaded from an untrusted site (which I don’t remember), the JavaScript was infobox.js and it was probably modified to download the file you mentioned.

I downloaded the JS from the original source and remove the “corrupt” file and the error stopped.